# how to restrict zero at position 0

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs

```js
$('input#abc').keypress(function(e){
   if (this.value.length == 0 && e.which == 48 || this.value.length == 0 && e.which == 46 ){
   //console.log(JSON.stringify(this.value.length[0]);
      return false;
      
   }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="text" id="abc" />
```

In the above snippet, zero and dot can't be entered when the length ==0. In this scenario it is working.

But when we type other than zero and dot, return to the first position, and enter zero or dot it is accepted.

I want to disallow zero and dot at any time as the first character.

Comment: User can still enter any alpha character and anyway keypress won't restrict user to paste any value to input.

Comment: @A.Wolff you are correct..

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That is because you are checking the condition only when your textarea length is zero. Instead, check for the textarea cursor position. If it is at zero and user enters invalid character, return false. Basically, replace your if condition from

```
 if (this.value.length == 0 && e.which == 48 || this.value.length == 0 && e.which == 46 )
```

to

```
if (this.selectionStart == 0 && e.which == 48 || this.selectionStart == 0 && e.which == 46 )
```

and if you want it to be more concise, you can do something (as recommended by @0x90) like

```
if (this.selectionStart == 0 && (e.which == 48 || e.which == 46 ))
```

Comment: What's wrong with: `if (this.selectionStart == 0 && (e.which == 48 || e.which == 46))`

Comment: and is it possible to restrict alphabets and special charecters in this script

Comment: yes, you can. You can have if condition for all banned characters. if(e.which == 48 || e.which == 46) { return false;} This will not care for which position you enter the character, it will completely ban it

Comment: @0x90 nothing wrong with it (in fact its better). I wanted to have an answer that is as close to the code that was written so the questioner can focus on the change.

Comment: @cdoshi I see. You could add an new line that suggest this. Please flag my comments to be deleted.

Answer (score 1):

You can check selectionStart to see cursor position

```
$('input#abc').keypress(function(e){ 
   if (e.currentTarget.selectionStart === 0){
     if(e.which == 48 || e.which == 46 ) {
       return false;
     }
   }
});
```

https://caniuse.com/#search=selectionStart

Comment: This is redundant because if `this.value.length === 0` then `e.currentTarget.selectionStart === 0` is always true. You should just check for `e.currentTarget.selectionStart === 0`

Comment: You’re right, thanks for pointing that out. I’ve edited the code